# Jetty runs correctly via maven, but incorrectly as a jar

Tags: maven, maven-2, jetty, spring-roo

(If my title is misleading/incorrect please suggest something more descriptive, that the best I could think of)

I've created my own web app using spring roo and have yet to edit any of the code. I am building and running the web app with maven and jetty. When I execute the following everything works fine.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

However when I package and then run the jar directly, I come across some strange problems.

```
mvn package
java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war
```

(Same thing with "mvn jetty:run-exploded")

The main page loads as it should, but when I click one of the navigation links (to create or list my models) I end up with these errors printed to the browser (http://localhost:8080/pages/main.jsf)

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /pages/main.jsf. Reason:

/pages/nameMeaning.xhtml @25,80 value="#{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}" Error Parsing: #{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}
Caused by:

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /pages/nameMeaning.xhtml @25,80 value="#{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}" Error Parsing: #{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:351)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$DynamicValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:398)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:171)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:232)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:385)
... 95 more
Caused by: com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:

"}" ...
"." ...
"[" ...
">" ...
"gt" ...
"<" ...
"lt" ...
">=" ...
"ge" ...
"<=" ...
"le" ...
"==" ...
"eq" ...
"!=" ...
"ne" ...
"&&" ...
"and" ...
"||" ...
"or" ...
"*" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"?" ...
"/" ...
"div" ...
"%" ...
"mod" ...


at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:1664)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:1544)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(ELParser.java:147)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:74)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:139)
... 99 more
Caused by:
```

Please see the pom.xml file here: http://pastebin.com/6aPpYP47

Comment: You need to show people at least some of your `pom.xml`... for example the `<dependencies>` section (at least the parts referencing jetty) and the `<build>` section. Otherwise this question is nearly impossible to answer as is

Comment: @Stephen Connolly - sorry about that, I've added a link to the pom.xml. You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/6aPpYP47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at your [`pom.xml`](http://pastebin.com/6aPpYP47) it is clear that you are running different versions of Jetty. That may or may not be the root cause of your issue, but as the different versions implement different versions of the Servlet Container specification you may find that something which is a Servlet 3.0 feature works with Jetty 8 and doesn't work with Jetty 7 (which is Servlet 2.5 IIRC)

If you look at your plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You will notice that `jetty:run` will be using Jetty `8.1.4.v20120524` whereas when you inject the jetty-runner

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                  <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                    <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                  </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And run with `java -jar jetty-runner.jar namename.war` you are using Jetty `7.4.5.v20110725`

As somebody else has pointed out you are using EL 2.2 which is really a Servlet 3.0 feature, so perhaps you just need to upgrade to a [newer version of jetty runner](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mortbay.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-runner%22)

Comment: Hey, this worked and fixed the original problem. Thanks for helping a noob. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have the same problem, the version I am using for the jetty-runner is the latest version to date (8.1.6.v20120903). I only have a few web-services implemented in Jersey (no container or anything else). Everything runs fine with maven jetty:run but calling my web-service returns HTTP ERROR 404 when executed through jar file. Any hint?

Comment: Latest isn't always greatest. Also are you sure you have the same version of both maven plugin and jetty runner? Another issue could be that the classpath for jetty:run might be subtly different... Did you try jetty:run-war also to verify that the packaged war works? Other than that not much I can give from the zero info you have provided

Answer (score 2):

I'd got the same error and I resolved. Your question is wrong.

This is due to Expression Parser. You have used

```
#{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}
```

in your nameMeaning.xhtml. It is not valid EL for that parser. Either u need to change like

```
#{applicationBean.getColumnName}
```

and pass param like

```
 <f:param name="column" value="#{column}"/>
```

or use el-api-2.2.jar parser in jetty.

Comment: el-api is in pom.xml, I posted a copy of it over here: http://pastebin.com/6aPpYP47

Comment: The question is not wrong, the problem is that `jetty:run` is using a different version of jetty from `java -jar jetty-runner.jar target/*.war` and those different versions are implementing different versions of the EL specification, so as a result it works in `jetty:run` which is using Servlet 3.0 and therefore EL 2.2 but not with `java -jar jetty-runner.jar target/*.war` which is using Servlet 2.5 and therefore JSP 2.1 which is effectively EL 2.1