# Jersey web-service runs fine with maven jetty:run but returns HTTP 404 with jetty-runner.jar

Tags: maven, heroku, jetty

I have a single web-service implemented in Jersey (no container or anything else). When I run it through `maven jetty:run`, it works fine but I get the HTTP ERROR 404 when I use `java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port 9090 target/*.war`
I checked a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241989/jetty-runs-correctly-via-maven-but-incorrectly-as-a-jar) but the solution does not work for me.
Here's how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.22</version>
    <configuration>
        <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>9090</port>
            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
        </connectors>
        <jetty-config>jetty.xml</jetty-config>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>8.1.6.v20120903</version>
                        <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would appreciate any hint to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you base this on [Deploy a Java Web Application that launches with Jetty Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner)?  Perhaps you have something special in your `jetty.xml` file that is making it run differently with `jetty:run`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, James. I am following the heroku guidelines. My project consists of only one class providing a simple web-service.

I did not modify jetty.xml, nor did I create a new one.

Comment: I probably need to recreate this to see what the problem is.  But alternatively you can use Grizzly instead of Jetty.  Here is an example of that: https://github.com/jamesward/jaxrsbars

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try Grizzly. The problem is that jetty-runner.jar has no problem running the HelloWorld example in the heroku guidelines but when I only have a web-service like this (http://pastebin.com/F5GEhzXM), my web-service does not get called.

Comment: Well, it worked with Grizzly, thanks to your tutorial on github. I am still wondering what was wrong with jetty-runner.jar!

Comment: Here is a little sample application that uses Jetty Runner + JAX-RS (Jersey):
https://github.com/jamesward/hello-java-jaxrs

It works on Heroku.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me find the issue:
The artifactId of my project is XXX. When I use `mvn jetty:run`, the url looks like this:
http://localhost:9090/XXX/path/to/service. It does not return anything by calling: 
http://localhost:9090/path/to/service.  
  
However, when I change it to `java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port 9090 target/*.war`, the url should be 
http://localhost:9090/path/to/service 
and not the other one (http://localhost:9090/XXX/path/to/service). I don't know what caused this setting, but at least I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the artifactId of my project was XXX. When I used mvn jetty:run, the url looked like this: `localhost:9090/XXX/path/to/service`. It did not return anything by calling: `localhost:9090/path/to/service`. However, when I change it to `java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port 9090 target/*.war`, the url should be `localhost:9090/path/to/service` and not the other one (`localhost:9090/XXX/path/to/service`).

I don't know what caused this setting, but at least I can get it to work.