# Webapp runs correctly with jetty 9 maven plugin, but not with jetty runner

Tags: jsf-2, jetty, embedded-jetty

Being new to Maven, I'm trying to make an **executable jar of my webapp with an embedded jetty**. Unfortunately, I'm having many difficulties achieving this, and decided to follow a step-by-step progression: first using jetty-maven-plugin (OK, with a lot of pain), then using jetty-runner (KO, the matter of this SO question), and finally using embedded jetty (KO).

I've spent so much time doing this, having different exceptions depending on the jetty version and pulled so much hair out, that I finally decided to ask the community for some help.

I hope this question won't be marked as a duplicate of [SO #12241989](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241989/jetty-runs-correctly-via-maven-but-incorrectly-as-a-jar) (or any other similar), because I have the same kind of problem, but clearly not the same root cause since I'm using the same version of jetty-maven-plugin and jetty-runner.

## Context

webapp uses JSF2 (mojarra 2.2.8) + CDI (weld) + Primefaces + Websockets

## Configuration

### 1. Jetty plugin

**excerpt from pom.xml**

```
     <properties>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.7</java.version>
            <jetty.groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</jetty.groupId>
            <jetty.version>9.0.4.v20130625</jetty.version>
            <jetty.descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</jetty.descriptor>
            <jetty.env>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml</jetty.env>
            <jetty.contextPath>/</jetty.contextPath>
            <jetty.overrideDescriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web-override.xml</jetty.overrideDescriptor>
            <myfaces.version>2.2.5</myfaces.version>
            <mojarra.version>2.2.8</mojarra.version>
    </properties>
    ...
    <plugin>
            <groupId>${jetty.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>${jetty.contextPath}</contextPath>
                    <descriptor>${jetty.descriptor}</descriptor>
                    <jettyEnvXml>${jetty.env}</jettyEnvXml>
                    <overrideDescriptor>${jetty.overrideDescriptor}</overrideDescriptor>
                </webApp>
                <contextXml>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-context.xml
                </contextXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**jetty-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
     <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>
                -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator
            </Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

**jetty-env.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
 <Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

 <New id="appManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx" />
        </Arg>
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg />
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

**jetty-web-override.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
<!--    CDI-->
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
    <!-- mojarra -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

With this configuration, the application runs correctly. *sigh of relief*

### 2. Jetty runner

I believe the easiest way to reproduce the above configuration with jetty runner is using a jetty context xml file that describes my webapp. So I ended up with the following context file :

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war">target/myapp.war</Set>
  <Set name="descriptor">src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</Set>
  <Set name="overrideDescriptor">src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web-override.xml</Set>
  <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>
                -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator
            </Item>
        </Array>
  </Set>

  <New id="appManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg />
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>

</Configure>
```

Then when I run the jetty runner (with the same version):

```
java -jar jetty-runner-9.0.4.v20130625.jar context.xml
```

...everything seems OK, except the (annoying) fact that the startup listener of my app (annotated with Servlet 3.0 `@WebListener`) does not start.

And if I try to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/`, I get the following stack trace:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

   Problem accessing /. Reason:
    Server Error

  Caused by:

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /index.xhtml @119,66 src="/WEB-INF/include/#{applicationManager.layout}.xhtml" /index.xhtml @119,66 src="/WEB-INF/include/#{appli
cationManager.layout}.xhtml": java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:358)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValue(TagAttributeImpl.java:322)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:112)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @119,66 src="/WEB-INF/include/#{applicationManager.layout}.xhtml": java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
```

If I try to enforce the listening of my StartupListener class by specifying in web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>fr.mygroup.myapp.listeners.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

...I get the same error.

Anyway, the fact that my StartupListener is not listened is clearly not the cause of the error but a consequence. But I can't figure out what's wrong with my jetty-runner configuration.

I desperately feel like it's a long way to go to an executable überjar of my webapp :(

## Appendix

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <jetty.groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</jetty.groupId>
        <jetty.version>9.0.4.v20130625</jetty.version>
        <jetty.descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</jetty.descriptor>
        <jetty.env>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml</jetty.env>
        <jetty.contextPath>/</jetty.contextPath>
        <jetty.overrideDescriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web-override.xml</jetty.overrideDescriptor>
        <myfaces.version>2.2.5</myfaces.version>
        <mojarra.version>2.2.8</mojarra.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
<plugin>
                <groupId>${jetty.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>${jetty.contextPath}</contextPath>
                        <descriptor>${jetty.descriptor}</descriptor>
                        <jettyEnvXml>${jetty.env}</jettyEnvXml>
                        <overrideDescriptor>${jetty.overrideDescriptor}</overrideDescriptor>
                    </webApp>
                    <contextXml>
                        ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-context.xml
                    </contextXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ebi-repo</id>
            <name>The EBI internal repository</name>
            <url>http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~maven/m2repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${mojarra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces 5.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Biomodels API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ac.ebi.biomodels</groupId>
            <artifactId>biomodels-wslib</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Ganymed SSH -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.ethz.ganymed</groupId>
            <artifactId>ganymed-ssh2</artifactId>
            <version>262</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Atmosphere -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```